# How to remove ads for paid membership in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a wordpress website in which i dont want to show ads to paid membership. the website will be an online course website. I am using lifterlms plugin to create membership.

Please help

Comment: Please provide more context. What ad network (if any) are you using? Are ads being injected via a plugin, custom js, a theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the list of hooks which LifterLms provide check if by using the hook such a condition that if user login then they can not see ads or if user had membership then also hide the ads

https://github.com/gocodebox/lifterlms/blob/master/includes/llms.template.hooks.php